# Number to Country Conversion

Tags: geography, matches

***Move 3 matchsticks from the number 808 to form the name of a country***

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to an earlier answer I add

> **LAOS**
>
>  Move the bottom match from the first **8** to leave **A**
>  Leave the **O** intact
>  Move the bottom left and upper right matches from the last **8** to leave **S**
>
>  Use these three matches to create a new **L** on the left.

Comment: This answer is exactly what was in my mind. The other answer in the thread came as a surprise!

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> **TOGO**

You remove

> the middle stick from both "8's" and the upper right stick from "0" and with these three sticks you form the letter "T" on the left. The number 808 has now become **"TOGO"**

Comment: This answer was not in my mind at all. Even though the third letter is somewhat ambiguous, I accept your answer. I just feel the other answer in the thread is more concrete.

Comment: No prob. I agree with you on that so I don't mind him getting the check mark.

Comment: Since a T requires only two matches, we can use the third match to make the G look more like a G. PS: Weather Vane's gender is unspecified in their profile, so defaulting to a male pronoun feels like a sign of our unconscious biases.